# MSChart Control Databinding from Source

Tags: sql, vb.net, charts, mschart

I've got a Problem with Databinding my Source to MS Charts.

```
    Dim SQL As New clsSQLConnect
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand


    cmd.Connection = SQL.SQLconn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Nachkalk"


    Form1.Chart1.DataSource = cmd
    Form1.Chart1.Series.Add("Price")
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Price").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Price").XValueMember = "Price"
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Price").YValueMembers = "Customer"
    Form1.Chart1.DataBind()
    SQL.closeSQL()
```

It does not even Display anything in my Chart.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I already tried it with Datasets.

Comment: I have no experience DataBinding from a DB, but what if your SQL is instead: `SELECT Price, Customer FROM Nachkalk`

Comment: Please look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766.aspx